# XSLT find sum from a number contains in a string input

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to get sum of numbers inside a string and find total of it.
Below is my input xml

```
<Order> 
<OrderItems>
    <OrderItem>         
        <OtherItem refs="SRV8_SP1P-12572566313805090059-1-8/SGD~163.10#SP1P-12572566313805090059-1">                
        </OtherItem>            
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>         
        <OtherItem refs="SRV8_SP1P-12572566313805090059-1-8/SGD~180.00#SP1P-12572566313805090059-1">                
        </OtherItem>        
    </OrderItem>
</OrderItems>
```

I use below template

```
<Amount>
    <xsl:for-each select="Order/OrderItems/OrderItem">          
                <xsl:call-template name="sumOriginalAmount">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Amount>   

<xsl:template name="sumOriginalAmount">
<xsl:param name="nodes" />
<xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />
<xsl:variable name="current" select="$nodes[1]" />
<xsl:if test="$current">
    <xsl:call-template name="sumOriginalAmount">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
        <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + (number(substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($current/OtherItem/@refs,'/'),'~'),'#')))" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not($current)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sum" />
</xsl:if>
```

</xsl:template>

But it returns result as concatenated value of string

```
<Amount CurCode="SGD">163.1180.0</Amount>
```

I need total of these two as

```
<Amount CurCode="SGD">343.0</Amount>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `for-each`, select `OrderItems`, for the `nodes` param `select="OrderItem"`.

```
  <xsl:template match="Order">
    <Amount>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderItems">          
                    <xsl:call-template name="sumOriginalAmount">
                        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="OrderItem"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Amount> 
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sumOriginalAmount">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" />
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="$nodes[1]" />
        <xsl:if test="$current">
            <xsl:call-template name="sumOriginalAmount">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + (number(substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($current/OtherItem/@refs,'/'),'~'),'#')))" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not($current)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: But here OrderItem is repeating, could you please elaborate. I tried this, but did not work.

Comment: @UmaimathThonikkadavan, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: I tried it at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcwZ and it does output a single amout `<Amount>343.1</Amount>`. If that is not what you want you might want to edit your question and explain in more detail whether you want a single sum for the complete XML or for each `Order` or in what way the suggested code does not fix your problem. I have just tried to fix the code from the input to compute a single value, not sure whether that reflects your needs.

Comment: Hi Martin, it got worked perfectly fine, I had a check in between, <xsl:when test="contains(OrderItem/OrderItemID,'BAG')"> , here I missed to add OrderItem as the for each changed to OrderItems. Thank you!